# Is woodworking on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

This question has recently been posted:

[What type of thin or light wood is suitable for making box joints?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/186/84)

Do we handle questions like this, or do we consider them to be a better fit for DIY.SE?

Comment: Ha. I just asked this question http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/57/do-we-limit-the-scope-of-woodworking-questions do you think mine might be more well rounded. DIY.SE is not the place for this WW.SE would be though.

Comment: Yes, you can ask questions about woodworking here.